# Batch List all files in a directory with relative paths

Tags: batch-file

Goodmorning all,

I am having an bit of trouble with the listning of all files including the files in subdirs and subsubdirs.

I have found on this site an script that will do the trick however i must place it inside the dir that i want to be listed.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
  set "file=%%~A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !file:~2! >>test.dat
  endlocal
)
```

That is what i have but i cant set an path that i want.
For example

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /p c:\ /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
```

i have added the /p c:\ so it will check the c:\ but it wont do anything.

Could someone explain it to me what i need to do to let it work?

With kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a list of files a folders you can try the `dir` command like so:

```
dir /s /b /o c:\my-directory
```

This will crawl all the folders and sub folders and give you all the files